# Install Firefox on Google Colab and Access using Public URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install Firefox on Google Colab and access it Interface using Public URL.

**My Code :**

```
!apt-get update
!pip install pyngrok
!pip install selenium
!apt-get install firefox -y

from pyngrok import ngrok
import subprocess

# Launch the web browser
subprocess.Popen(['firefox', '--headless', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--remote-debugging-port=8888'])

# Wait for Firefox to start
import time
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the delay if needed

# Create a public URL using ngrok
ngrok.set_auth_token('2Rds12n2TZQrrPo0SF7F4i7ZmGg_3qDDTjYdSAyH31y55mJuB')
browser_url = ngrok.connect(8888).public_url

# Display the public URL
print("Web Browser URL:", browser_url)

#Verification 

!firefox --version
!lsof -i :8888
!netstat :8888

# Keep the cell running until interrupted
try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Cell execution interrupted.")
finally:
    # Stop ngrok
    ngrok.kill()
```

**Error :**

***After opening Public URL in my web browser, it showing bad request.***